# How to add legends in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Probably very basic question about the legends in ggplot2 (sorry i am basic user user of R), I use this:

```
p<-ggplot(bAfr_topS1, aes(MAF, V3))+ geom_point()
p <- p+  geom_point(data=bEur_topS1,aes(MAF,V3),colour="red")+
  geom_point(data = bSas_topS1, aes(MAF, V3), colour="blue")

print(p)
```

but can't see the legends in output plot, any suggestion please? what should i add in?

Comment: You're using `ggplot2` the *wrong* (not optimal) way. Please check online tutorials (you need to bind your data and set color in `aes`).

Comment: Please share a reproducible example. Or use dput, so that others can understand your data and problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give specific help without any data, but to illustrate the point @PoGibas is making and to get you started, try the following

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_rows(list(AF = bAfr_topS1, EU = bEur_topS1, PK = bSas_topS1), .id = "src") %>%
    ggplot(aes(MAF, V3, colour = as.factor(src))) +
    geom_point()
```

This assumes that `bAfr_topS1`, `bEur_topS1`, `bSas_topS1` all have the same column structure.

Comment: You should load `dplyr` or add `dplyr::\`%>%\``

Comment: Aaah very true @PoGibas; thanks:-)

Comment: Almost sorted! legends are 1 2 & 3, can i change 1 as AF, 2 as EU and 3 as PK?

Comment: @bha made an edit. Please try again.

Comment: Sorted! many thanks

Comment: Great and you’re very welcome @bha

Comment: PS Please consider closing the question by setting the green check mark next to the answer. This will help future SO users and tidy up SO questions/answers.